# Stacked barplot in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, altair

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': {0: 'Category 1',  1: 'Category 1',  2: 'Category 1',  3: 'Category 1',  4: 'Category 1',  5: 'Category 1',  6: 'Category 1',  7: 'Category 2',  8: 'Category 2',  9: 'Category 2',  10: 'Category 2',  11: 'Category 2',  12: 'Category 2',  13: 'Category 2'},
 'Subcategory': {0: 'Subcategory 1',  1: 'Subcategory 2',  2: 'Subcategory 3',  3: 'Subcategory 4',  4: 'Subcategory 5',  5: 'Subcategory 6',  6: 'Subcategory 7',  7: 'Subcategory 1',  8: 'Subcategory 2',  9: 'Subcategory 3',  10: 'Subcategory 4',  11: 'Subcategory 5',  12: 'Subcategory 6',  13: 'Subcategory 7'},
 'Percentage': {0: 7.682670448608449,  1: 49.28051034787686,  2: 21.557236565207138,  3: 14.946332233068556,  4: 2.7770308859363673,  5: 2.776563009324076,  6: 0.9796565099785499,  7: 20.710773297856395,  8: 9.464304900075165,  9: 12.678873097708376,  10: 0.21418215100524463,  11: 36.07809818629485,  12: 18.39586789285812,  13: 2.4579004742018524}})
```

1. Plot A: A single bar representing the `Category` feature, where the height of the stacks corresponds to the total percentage for each category.
2. Plot B: A single bar representing the `Subcategory` feature, with the height of the stacks corresponding to the percentage for each subcategory.
3. Both plots should have a shared Y-axis, and the total percentage for `Category 1` in plot A should equal the combined percentage of all subcategories belonging to `Category 1` in the plot B.
4. Consistent Positioning: Related to point (3), the position of each subcategory in Plot B has to be consistent with the position of the `Category` it belongs to in Plot A.

Currently, I'm using this workaround by creating two columns and placing one plot in each column. However, I'm struggling to make the plots comparable:

```
col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
with col1:
    st.plotly_chart(fig_from_plot_A)

with col2:
    st.plotly_chart(fig_from_plot_B)
```

The ideal result is the one below. When a user reads the left bar stacked plot will have a general idea of the percentage of Categories, and it will be able to go deeper seeing the right bar stacked plot where he will be able to identify which subcategories have the highest percentage contribution to each Category.

[image]